# Quantization levels

Tags: python, image-processing

i am trying to make a RGB histogram consisting of 512 entries with eight quantization levels(bins) per color channel. is this possible? if yes can you help me out. Thank you

```
int[] binnedHistogram(ImageProcessor ip) {
    int K = 256;
    int B = 32;
    int [] H =new int[B]
    int w = ip.getWidth();
    int h = ip.getHeight();
    
    for (int v = 0; v < h; v++) {
        for (int u = 0; u < w; u++) {
            int a = ip.getpixel(u, v);
            int i = a * B / K;
            H[i] = H[i] + 1;
        }
    }
    
    return H;
}
```

I tied this but it doesn't work

Comment: Is this python? It looks like C/C++

Comment: yes it is python disregard the code

Comment: Then add the Python code you tried, as well as an example input and the expected output for such input!

Comment: i don't have the python code

Comment: And you don't have an example input and an example output? I'm afraid this question will remain unanswered.